# C++ thrift client: how to send buffer without length?

Tags: c++, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have my c++ client application and Java server.
The client app connects and send data to the server.

For example I send integer value:

```
boost::shared_ptr<TSocket> socket(new TSocket(hostMS, portMS));
    boost::shared_ptr<TFramedTransport> transport(new TFramedTransport(socket));
    boost::shared_ptr<TBinaryProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

transport->open();
protocol->writeI32(0xCA12EEAA);
transport->writeEnd();
transport->flush();
```

The server side code is:

```
int nMagic =0;
// int nLen = in.readInt(); <------------here is I read the length
int ch1 = in.read();
                int ch2 = in.read();
                int ch3 = in.read();
                int ch4 = in.read();
                if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
                    throw new EOFException();
             nMagic = ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
```

The question is: 
When I added one more read integer (see my comment) it works ok. First of all i read the length (4 bytes) and then data - integer.

It means that the client sends 
length (int)
data (int)

but server reads only data.

How I can send data only? I can use another thrift transport or protocol or use non-thrift library...

Comment: How would the other side know how much data to read without a length attribute?

Comment: Hmm.. but its fact. The server does not read it. May be it was read before in basic Java class. I hav emade another experiment: run socket test utility Hercules (www.hw-group.com) and connected to the server, then sent hex value - the server received it successfully.

Answer (score 3):

The more general statement is, that the client-side Thrift protocol/transport stack must match the server-side, otherwise you are very likely to get in trouble.

E.g. if the server uses binary protocol, framed and multiplex transport, the client has to do exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

But if you use non-blocking sever ,then you must use TFramededTransport

Answer (score 0):

To use TBufferedTransport instead TFramededTransport because TFramedTransport adds (!) length before buffer.

Comment: Seems interesting. I guess this applies to all thrift platforms (python, node). How did yu come to this question - or why do you need the answer?